# toggler button position changes when clicked on different links

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on designing a Navigation bar for my website. I am facing some rendering problems when i switch from one link to another link in navigation bar. the size of toggle button expands and i am unable to find what the problem is. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

HTML code

```
<nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-sm  navbar-light bg-dark ">


            <div class="container" style="border: 5px solid green">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-white" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Mywebsite</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"    
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white " asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white " asp-area="" asp-page="/link1">link1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-white " asp-area="" asp-page="/link2">link2</a>
                        </li>
                        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1b6ec2;
  border-color: #1861ac;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #3dc4c4 !important;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    margin-left: 5rem;
   /*display:block;*/
}

.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
    width: 100%;
}

a.navbar-brand {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Is the link redirecting to a different page ? Have you tried copy and paste the navigation code in the other page where the toggler button position changes ?